# Reduce space at top and bottom of cover letter template

Tags: spacing, header-footer, letters

I am attempting to adapt this [letterhead template on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/brown-university-letterhead-example-letter/qvwjsqdgdqhv#.WpcsZOZG1hE) for my personal use. I need to produce a two-page letter, with the second page having one-inch margins top and bottom. I have attempted to alter `brownletter.cls` commands related to the `empty` pagestyle without success. If I comment out lines 93-107 in the .cls file, the header space is reduced, but not the footer space. How can I adapt the main .tex file or .cls class file for the desired result?

For example, editing the `main.tex` file to include the below code produces a document with large top and bottom margins on the second page, pushing text onto a third page. I want to consolidate to two pages.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{brownletter}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\name{Nesime Tatbul} % used as signature, if no signature is specified

\signature{Nesime Tatbul\\ Tex Merc}

\date{December 15, 2003} % if no date specified, today's date is used 

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Prof. Eli Upfal\\ 
               Brown University\\ 
               Box 1910\\ 
               Providence, RI 02912}

\opening{Dear Sir,}

\lipsum[1-9]

Thank you for your consideration.

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I thought I could reduce this space by editing this code in `brownletter.cls`

```
\renewcommand{\ps@empty}{
\setlength{\headheight}{1.375in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}
\renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\usebox{\emptyfoot}}
\renewcommand{\@evenhead}{}
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\usebox{\emptyfoot}}
}
```

I can reduce the top space by changing `\headheight` to 0.5in, but the space is pushed to the bottom. I tried adding a longer `\textheight` parameter to this snippet defining the empty page style, but this also increased the text height for the first page, pushing the text past the bottom margin.

Comment: Please post your MWE, preferably compilable, where you show what you have tried so far. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe